# Having issues with my file opening assignment

Tags: python

```
#Loops as long as user wants to continue
while True:
 #Required variables
 totalGrade = 0
 count = 0
 passed = 0
 failed = 0
 #Prints the greeting message
 print("Course Grades Summary Report ...\n")
 #Takes file name from the user
 fileName = input("Enter name of course file:  ")
 #Prints the header of the report
 print()
 print("-"*60)
 print("{0:>41}".format("Broward College Grades Summary"))
 print("-"*60)
 #Opens the given file in read mode
 with open(fileName, "r") as f:
    #Reads the entire file lines into a list
    content = f.readlines()
    #Reads course name, professor name and term values
    courseName = content[0].replace("\n","")
    professor = content[1].replace("\n","")
    term = content[2].replace("\n","")
    #Displays course name, professor and term values
    print()
    print(courseName)
    print("Professor: {0:<32} Term:{1}".format(professor,term))

    #Displays student name and grade header
    print("{0:<32}{1}".format("\nStudent Name","Grade"))
    print("-"*40)
    #Loops through every line further
    for i in range(3, len(content), 2):
        #Reads student name and grade
        name = content[i].replace("\n","")
        grade = int(content[i+1].replace("\n",""))
        #Calculates total of grades,number of students,
        #number of students passed and number of students failed
        totalGrade += grade
        count += 1
        if grade < 60:
            failed += 1
        else:
            passed += 1
        #Displays name and grade
            print("{0:<32}{1}".format(name, grade))

        #Calculates average grade and passing percentage
        averageGrade = totalGrade/count
        passingPercentage = (passed / (passed + failed))*100
    #Displays output
    print("\nStudents' Performance")
    print("-"*40)
    print("Passed: {0:<25}Failed: {1}".format(passed, failed))
    print("Passing Percent: {0:.0f}%".format(passingPercentage))
    print("Average Grade: {0:.0f}".format(averageGrade))
    #Reads whether user wants to continue or not
    choice = input("Would you like to process another file (y/n)? ")
    if choice.lower() == 'n':
        break
```

Once ran the user should be prompted to input a course ID "COP1000C.txt"

I then see about half of my desired result but not fully.

Also if I put the wrong course in I'm supposed to receive an error prompt but I don't receive that either. Not too sure what Im doing wrong can someone lead me in the right direction, thanks in advance. Also once ran I receive

```
grade = int(content[i+1].replace("\n",""))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have the following lines inside of your for loop when you want to have them outside:

```
averageGrade = totalGrade/count
passingPercentage = (passed / (passed + failed))*100
```

As for your error, try putting `len(content) + 1` as the end argument for your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not checking whether the input file exists of not, and is assuming that the file exists with the correct format.

Modify the code with the 'os.path.isfile()' function to check if the file exists, has at least 3 lines, and has enough lines to read the students' names and grades. If any check fails, an error message will display. The loop will continue and ask the user to enter another file name.

```
import os.path

# Loops as long as user wants to continue
while True:
    # Required variables
    totalGrade = 0
    count = 0
    passed = 0
    failed = 0

    # Prints the greeting message
    print("Course Grades Summary Report ...\n")

    while True:
        # Takes file name from the user
        fileName = input("Enter name of course file: ")
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            print("Error: file does not exist.")
            continue  # continue with the loop
        else:
            break

    # Prints the header of the report
    print()
    print("-" * 60)
    print("{0:>41}".format("Broward College Grades Summary"))
    print("-" * 60)

    # Reads the entire file lines into a list
    with open(fileName, "r") as f:
        content = f.readlines()

        # Check if the file has at least 3 lines
        if len(content) < 3:
            print("Error: invalid file format.")
            continue  # continue loop

        # Reads course name, professor name and term values
        courseName = content[0].replace("\n", "")
        professor = content[1].replace("\n", "")
        term = content[2].replace("\n", "")

        # Displays course name, professor and term values
        print()
        print(courseName)
        print("Professor: {0:<32} Term {1}".format(professor,term))

        # Displays student name and grade header
        print("{0:<32}{1}".format("\nStudent Name", "Grade"))
        print("-"*40)

        # Loops through every line further
        for i in range(3, len(content), 2):
            # Check if there are enough lines left
            if i+1 >= len(content):
                print("Error: invalid file format.")
                break  # exit loop

            # Reads student name and grade
            name = content[i].replace("\n", "")
            grade = int(content[i+1].replace("\n", ""))

            # Calculates total of grades,number of students,
            # number of students passed and number of students failed
            totalGrade += grade
            count += 1
            if grade < 60:
                failed += 1
            else:
                passed += 1

            # Displays name and grade
            print("{0:<32}{1}".format(name, grade))

        # Calculates average grade and passing percentage
        averageGrade = totalGrade/count
        passingPercentage = (passed / (passed + failed))*100

        # Displays output
        print("\nStudents' Performance")
        print("-"*40)
        print("Passed: {0:<25}Failed: {1}".format(passed, failed))
        print("Passing Percent: 
{0:.0f}%".format(passingPercentage))
        print("Average Grade: {0:.0f}".format(averageGrade))

    # Reads whether user wants to continue or not
    choice = input("Would you like to process another file (y/n)? ")
    if choice.lower() == 'n':
        break
```